# Why is the purpose of the "else" clause following a "for" or "while" loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a Python beginner. I find that the `else` in `for`-`else` and `while`-`else` is completely unnecessary. Because `for` and `while` will finally run to `else`, and we can use the usual lines instead.

For example:

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    print i
else:
    print 'over'
```

and

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    print i
print 'over'
```

are the same.

So why does Python have `else` in `for`-`else` and `while`-`else`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are wrong about the semantics of for/else.  The else clause runs only if the loop completed, for example, if a break statement wasn't encountered.

The typical for/else loop looks like this:

```
for x in seq:
    if cond(x):
        break
else:
    print "Didn't find an x I liked!"
```

Think of the "else" as pairing with all of the "if's" in the loop body.  Your samples are the same, but with "break" statements in the mix, they are not.

A longer description of the same idea: http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201110/forelse.html

Answer (score 1):

The `for ... else` statement is used to implement search loops.

In particular, it handles the case where a search loop fails to find anything.

```
for z in xrange(10):
    if z == 5:
        # We found what we are looking for
        print "we found 5"
        break # The else statement will not execute because of the break
else:

    # We failed to find what we were looking for
    print "we failed to find 5"
    z = None

print 'z = ', z
```

output:

```
we found 5
z =  5
```

That search is the same as

```
z = None
for z in xrange(10):
    if 5 == z:
        # We found what we are looking for
        break

if z == None:
    print "we failed to find 5"
else:
    print "we found 5"

print 'z = ', z
```

Remember that `for` doesn't initialize z if the search list is empty (i.e. `[]`).  That's why we have to ensure that z is defined when we use it after the search.  The following will raise an exception because `z` is not defined when we try to print it.

```
for z in []:
    if 5 == z:
        break

print "z = ",z
```

output

```
    print "z = ",z
NameError: name 'z' is not defined
```

In summary, the `else` clause will execute whenever the `for` loop terminates naturally.  If a break or an exception occurs in the `for` loop the `else` statement will not execute.